# AsyncTypeahead textbox should clear on backspace

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

The text in the AsyncTypeahead textbox need to make white on the backspace. I have tried different methods by applying CSS, some method change, but that is not suitable. Can you anyone please suggest how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.
Below I have added the code used:

```
<AsyncTypeahead
   className=""
   id="typeahead"
   delay={800}
   emptyLabel="please select"
   ignoreDiacritics={true}
   minLength={3}
   onSearch={this.onSearch}
   placeholder="Insert text to search"
   promptText={this.searchtext}
   searchText={this.searchtext}
   renderMenuItemChildren={(selectedItem: State, props) => {

   }}
 />
```

[image: the result is coming as per the pic]

[image: expected]

Comment: Hi @Vinay, can you please clarify your question? From the two screenshots you posted, it seems like you want to get rid of the hint, though from the title it seems like you want to clear the input entirely.

Comment: Hi, @ericgio yes need to get rid of the Hint.   the solution is can get rid by overriding the CSS **.rbt-input-hint{display: none !important;}** by this we can achieve that easily